# Prove/ give counter example: $\lim_{z\to\ w}f(z)=\infty\iff\lim_{z\to\ w}Re(f)=lim_{z\to\ w}Im(f)=\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, limits, analytic-functions

Let $f$ be a complex function defined in a deleted neighbourhood of w. Prove or disprove by counter-example:

$\lim_{z\to\ w}f(z)=\infty\iff\lim_{z\to\ w}Re(f)=lim_{z\to\ w}Im(f)=\infty$

I know this is not true so i'm trying to give a counter-example,
I want to check $f(z)=(6z^2 +1)/(2z^2 -50)$ around $w=5$.

$lim_{z\to\ 5}f(z)=\infty$ However I can't seem to be able to split the function into real and imaginary parts in order to check the limits of each. Is this procedure correct?

Comment: Why not try something much simper like $f(x,y) = 1/x$ at $z=0$? You didn't specify that the function had to be analytic so you can take any function that is always real and has a singularity to get a counterexample.

Comment: Let's assume the function has to be complex

Comment: It *is* complex. Add $i$ to it if you want.

Comment: Thank you that helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disprove:

$f(z)=\frac{1}{||z-w||}\Rightarrow \lim_{z\rightarrow w}{f(z)
}=\infty \land lim_{z\rightarrow w}{Re(f)}=\infty \land Im(f)=0$